# Перегрузка операторов [] и ()

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, c++

Покажите какой-нибудь толковый пример перегрузки оператора [] и ()

Comment: Что-то было на: [habrahabr.ru][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/132014/

Comment: там недостаточно информации про [], ()

Comment: А что непонятно? И что значит "толковый"? Смотри классику: Страуструп, Лафоре, Джосаттис. Там куча хороших примеров по перегрузке этих операторов.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Арифметическая прогрессия. Оператор [] возвращает n-ый член, а () - сумму первых n членов арифметической прогрессии:

```
class ArithProgression
{
public:
    ArithProgression(int a1, int d) {this->a1=a1, this->d=d;}
    int operator[](int n) {return a1+d*(n-1);}
    int operator()(int n) {return (2*a1+d*(n-1))*n/2;}

private:
    int a1, d;
};

int main()
{
    ArithProgression ap1(1, 2);
    cout << ap1[6] << ' ' << ap1(6) << endl;
    ArithProgression ap2(100, -3);
    cout << ap2[14] << ' ' << ap2(14) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Отвечаю на вопрос из комментариев:*

Через оператор [] это делается вот так:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    ...Другой код...
    float& operator[](int index) {return ((float*)this)[index];}

    float x, y, z, w;
};

class Matrix
{
public:
    ...Другой код...
    Vector& operator[](int index) {return data[index];}

    Vector data[4];
};
```

Для матриц и векторов оператор [] можно вообще не перегружать. Если хранить матрицу как массив векторов, можно переопределить `operator Vector*`. Таким образом, матрица будет неявно указателем на вектор, а указатель сам поддерживает []. Для вектора можно тоже определить `operator float*`. Вот реализация этого способа:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    ...Другой код...
    operator float*() {return (float*)this;}

    float x, y, z, w;
};

class Matrix
{
public:
    ...Другой код...
    operator Vector*() {return data;}

    Vector data[4];
};

Использовать оба варианта можно так:

Matrix matrix;
...Инициализация матрицы...
cout << matrix[1][2] << ' ' << matrix[1].z << endl;
if(matrix[1][2]!=matrix[1].z) cout << "Error!" << endl; //Выводить не должно, так как индекс 2 соответствует z-координате.
```

Comment: а как перезагрузить , например, [][] ?

Comment: Я бы для этого сделал внутренний класс, который бы возвращался  operator[] основного класса и был бы в свою очередь перегружен на [].

Comment: ну , например, matrix[1][2] = 10; 
как токое сделать ?

Comment: >ну , например, matrix[1][2] = 10; - как токое сделать ?

 Дополнил свой ответ.

Answer (score 7):

А бестолковый можно? Пожалуйста:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>
using namespace std;
class dumbexample {
private:
    int *arr;
    int n;
public:
    dumbexample(int n1) {
        n = n1;
        arr = new int[n];
        bzero(arr, n*sizeof(int));
    }
    ~dumbexample() {}
    int& operator[] (int i) {return arr[i];} 
    int operator() (int i) {return arr[i]*i;}
};
int main() {
    dumbexample a(6);
    a[2] = 5;    
    cout << a[2] << endl;
    cout << a(2) << endl;
}
```