# Массив без выхода за пределы C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Мне нужно массив или вектор без выхода за пределы.
Что это такое? допустим 
Создаю вектор или массив на 10 символов типа int
Все 10 элементов равны 10
когда беру a[0],a[4],a[9] == 10;
но как сделать так что бы

```
a[10 (это 0) ] == 10 
a[12 (это 2) ] == 10
```

желательно ещё для отрицательных чисел

Comment: Создайте свой класс и перегрузите в нем operator[]

Comment: я не умею это делать

Comment: не умеете делать что, писать классы или перегружать операторы? :) [посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81432/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8)

Comment: Ну просто используйте не `a[i]`, а `a[i%10]`...

Comment: @Harry: Не сработает для отрицательных чисел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, как получить индекс, не выходящий за пределы массива при отрицательных индексах, то можно индекс массива вычислять так:

```
i < 0 ? -i%10 : i % 10
```

Например:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for(int i=-12; i<12; ++i){
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i < 0 ? -i%10 : i % 10] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе будет:

```
a[-12] = 3
a[-11] = 2
a[-10] = 1
a[-9] = 10
a[-8] = 9
a[-7] = 8
a[-6] = 7
a[-5] = 6
a[-4] = 5
a[-3] = 4
a[-2] = 3
a[-1] = 2
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 4
a[4] = 5
a[5] = 6
a[6] = 7
a[7] = 8
a[8] = 9
a[9] = 10
a[10] = 1
a[11] = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Создайте свой класс и перегрузите в нем `operator[]` (я сделаю здесь в виде шаблона):

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T *arr;
    int size;

public:
    Array(uint _size = 10); //по умолчанию размер массива = 10;
    ~Array();
    T& operator[](uint index);
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(uint _size)
{
    if (_size == 0) { _size = 1; }
    arr = new T[_size];
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete [] arr;
}

template <typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](uint _index)
{
    _index %= size;
    return arr[_index];
}
```

**NB** Возможно где то накосячил, так как давно не писал на плюсах, но принцип должен быть понятен.

Comment: Объявить деструктор забыли в теле класса. ИМХО, темплейты пока рано спрашивающему. P.S. Да, еще копирующий конструктор.

Comment: @andy.37 деструктор исправил, а насчет темплейтов... ну пусть покопается, хоть какую то работу сделает, САМ.

Answer (score -2):

Вообще, выходить за пределы выделяемой памяти не рекомендуется, может возникнуть ошибка segmentation fault. Вы можете создать иллюзию на такой массив, к примеру, создать класс которое заранее забронирует определенное количество мест в массиве.

```
class SomeArrayInt {
    int *a;
    public SomeArrayInt() {
        a = new int[1000];
        n = 1000;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = 10;
    }  
    int operator[](int k) {
        if(n < k) {
           delete [] a; 
           a = new int[k];
           n = k; 
           for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
               a[i] = 10; 
         }
         return a[k - 1];
    }
    ~SomeArrayInt() {
        delete [] a;
    }
}
```

Может ошибся где нить, но по идее как то так.

Comment: Вопрос вроде немножко не про это, насколько я понимаю автор хочет так обращаться к массиву, чтобы по индексам, большим чем размер массива возвращались элементы массива по пересчитанным индексам (скажем, размер 10, индекс 12 -> возвращаем элемент по индексу 2).