# Что значит " Реализовать перегруз-ку операции () (a(i)=b(j))."?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Объясните пожалуйста что требуется сделать в этой задаче?

> Создать несколько объектов  (например, a и b) разработанного класса.
>   Класс – вектор (одномерный массив). Реализовать для объектов данного
>   класса перегруз-ку операции  ()   (a(i)=b(j)).

Не могу понять ни что это за операция, ни что тут требуется.

Comment: Было уже подобное [перегрузка операторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81432/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, раз должно срабатывать присваивание

```
a(i) = b(j);
```

то вам нужно перегрузить оператор `()` так, чтобы он возвращал **ссылку** на соответствующий элемент.

Т.е. если у вас класс что-то вроде

```
class Vec
{
    ...
    int *data;
```

то вам нужно перегрузить примерно

```
    int& operator()(size_t i) { return data[i]; }
    const int& operator()(size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
```

можно добавить проверку выхода за границы массива.

Comment: Здравствуйте, не могу справится с задачей, не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, более подробно ответить на вопрос? Я имею ввиду код. Думаю для Вас это не составит большого труда, а для меня это трудно.

Comment: Это уже перебор - за полным решением вам нужно, скажем, [сюда](http://www.reshaem.net/?cGFydG5lcj03OTIy). Здесь, простите, все за вас не делают, только подталкивают в нужном направлении :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738191/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8