# Возможно ли реализовать перегрузку операции () в Java?

Tags: java, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Создать несколько объектов  (например, a и b) разработанного класса.
Класс – вектор (одномерный массив). Реализовать для объектов данного
класса перегрузку операции  `()`:   `(a(i)=b(j))`.

Comment: @defaultlocale я написал, что в Java нет перегрузки операторов. А тут операция. Может тут что-то особенное имеется в виду. Я просто не понял)

Comment: В Java нет перегрузки операторов. Да, но если очень сильно постараться, то можно изобразить перегрузку операторов. Зря закрыли вопрос да еще и зря минусуют...

Comment: Это ни фига не дубль. В псевдодубле в ответе речь идет о С++, никак не о Java

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит " Реализовать перегруз-ку операции () (a(i)=b(j))."?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736556/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-ai-bj)

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736635/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java#comment1122712_736635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В vanilla/plain Java нет перегрузки операторов.

Да, но если очень сильно постараться, то можно изобразить - через плагины к Java компилятору.

Есть например [решение по перегрузке арифметических операторов](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo) - со скобками конечно будет сложнее. Но если хорошо подумать, наверное можно выкрутиться.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, переопределить поведение операторов в Java нельзя.

В таких случаях обычно берут пример с [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) и создают методы `get` и `set`:

```
a.set(i, b.get(j));
```

В принципе для данного класса будет логично реализовать интерфейс `List` или воспользоваться одной из готовых реализаций (если задание допускает использование стандартных классов).

Также можете посмотреть в сторону языка Kotlin, он работает под JVM и предоставляет много синтаксического сахара, в том числе [переопределение оператора `()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke).