# Как привести дженерик к Number?

Tags: java

При сравнении 2х дженерик типов нужно сделать что-то типа

```
boolean test(T t,E e){
 return (Number)e>(Number)t
 }
```

Как это можно реализовать? Джава позволяет приводить дженерики к Integer & Double , но к Number почему-то нельзя

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `abstract class Number` и объекты которые вы используете должны

1. Быть потомками Number.
2. Number должен быть сравнимыми. В Java нет [перегрузки операторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736635/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java) так что нужно немного постараться.

И вообще сравнение 2 различных женерика в таком виде

Нужно знать хоть что-то о них по типу

```
boolean test(<? extends MyInterface> t,<? extends MyInterface> e){
 return ((MyInterface)e).isGreate((MyInterface)t)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С такими условиями задача супер нереальная:

```
boolean test(T t,E e){
   return (Number)e>(Number)t
}
```

Дженерики -- это всегда про объекты, а оператор > используется только с примитивами. Так что да, как уже объяснили, сравнивать нужно будет внутри какого-то метода.

Но самое-то главное, T и E -- разные классы, не состоящие в иерархических отношениях. Они в принципе несравнимы.

То есть это не значит, что вы не можете придумать велосипед с квадратными колёсами и граблями вместо руля. Это значит, что где-то в самой задумке зарыта какая-то принципиальная ошибка.

Вы бы поделились, что вам в принципе-то надо. В чём вообще задача состоит?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
boolean test(T t,E e){
   return convertToNumber(e) >convertToNumber(t)
}


Number convertToNumber(T t) {
    if (t instanceof Number)
       return (Number )t;
    return Double.valueOf(t.toString());
}
```

Comment: Я джаву еще не долго учу и многого не знаю, но разве можно сравнивать два объекта `Number` через `>`?

Comment: ну конечно нельзя сравнивать объекты так, правда я теперь уже и не понимаю, в случае с `Number` вполне может сработать `unboxing` и компилятор может быть даже и пропустит :) надо пробовать...