# Правильно ли я реализовал перезагрузку операции "()"?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, перегрузка-операторов

> Создать несколько объектов (например, a и b) разработанного класса.
>   Класс – вектор (одномерный массив). Реализовать для объектов данного
>   класса перегрузку операции `() (a(i)=b(j))`.

```
class vector {
    public:
        int ar[10];

    int &operator ()(int i)
    {
        if(i >= 0 && i < 10)
            return ar[i];
        else
            cout << "Выход за пределы массива" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector obj1, obj2;
    int a = 1, b = 11;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        obj1(i) = a++;
        obj2(i) = b++;
    }

    int tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        tmp = obj1(i);
        obj1(i) = obj2(i);
        obj2(i) = tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: По внешмену виду - да. Если запускается и выдает что ожидалось, то правильно.

Comment: @ffk Всё работает, вывод правильный.

Comment: Только добавьте в реализацию проверку на корректность индекса (>= 0 && < 10)

Comment: @rudolfninja Это где? У меня же массив из 10 элементов и в циклах по 10 всё везде.

Comment: В реализации оператора () `int &operator ()(int i)` если сюда передать, в качестве параметра, например, -1 или 12, то ваша программа сломается, т.к. происходит выход за пределы массива. Поэтому вам внутри реализации нужно делать проверку, что бы индекс был корректный. Вообще, это не обязательно и по заданию не надо, но лишним это точно не будет.

Comment: @rudolfninja Посмотрите, так?

Comment: Почти. У вас оператор должен всегда возвращать значение типа int. Когда выполнение переходит в ветку else, то будет просто сообщение на экране, но никакого значения не вернется. Можете сделать так: `if(i < 0) return ar[0]; else if (i > 9) return ar[9]; else return ar[i];`

Comment: Лучше при выходе за рамки генерировать исключение. Совет @rudolfninja плох тем, что вы не увидите ошибку. Проигнорировать исключение не получится :)

Comment: @Harry, я думал об этом. И это более правильный вариант, но вряд ли автор знаком с понятием исключений. Так же могут возникнуть ситуации, когда проброс исключения - не обязательная мера и можно все нормально обработать внутри оператора, но это зависит от поставленной задачи.

Comment: @rudolfninja Знаком вообще-то. Мне и без исключения сойдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не правильно. В языке С++ требуется, чтобы все пути выполнения не-`void` функции заканчивались явным `return`. В противном случае *поведение не определено*. Ваша реализация оператора `()` содержит `return` не во всех путях выполнения. То есть поведение вашей программы не определено.

Одним из возможных проявлений неопределенного поведения является отказ компилятора компилировать вашу программу. Качественные современные С++ компиляторы именно так и поступят, указав вам на тот факт, что не все пути выполнения в этой функции возвращают значение.