# Перегрузка оператора вызова функции?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Недавно вычитал про перегрузку оператора вызова функции `operator()`. И мне кажется это абсолютно бесполезно.

Не могли вы пожалуйста подсказать для чего это нужно делать и в каких случаях?

Comment: Ну, не пользуйтесь функторами, раз это бесполезно... Лямбда-функциями (они это, так сказать, за кулисами используют). И многим другим...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перегрузка операторов \[\] и ()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81432/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator()` довольно полезный. Если мы хотим представить объект класса как функцию, нам нужно перегрузить оператор круглые скобки. Это называеться функтор(функциональный объект).

*"А для чего?"* - спросите вы. Это облегчает жизнь: вместо `logger.log("Log this message");`, оптимальней будет `logger("Log this message");`. Вместо `divider.divide(T, T)` - просто `divider(T, T);`. Также удобно с двумерными массивами - `2x2_array(0, 4) = 62;`.

A `std::function`? Это продвинутый ООП-объект-указатель на функцию. И когда этому объекту мы присвоили какую-то функцию, как вызывать эту функцию через `std::function`? С помощию перегруженого оператора  `()`!

Это понятие широко используеться в STL. Одним из популярнейших прменений функторов является передача их в качестве аргументов алгоритмам. Тем самым можно регулировать поведение.

Answer (score 4):

`operator()` - это соглашение для удобства использования шаблонного кода. Некий шаблонный алгоритм для своей кастомизации принимает что-то, что может быть вызвано как функция, т.е. через запись с круглыми скобками `()`. Кол-во параметров, передаваемых внутри этих круглых скобок определяется задачей. Например, для алгоритма поиска `std::find_if` в качестве предиката можно передать обычную функцию, функтор (объект, в классе которого реализован как раз `operator()`, или лямбду:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool f(int) { return true; }

struct F {
    bool operator()(int) { return true; }  
};

auto l = [](int) { return true; };

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    
    std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);   // обычная функция 
    std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), F()); // функтор
    std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), l);   // лямбда
}
```

При этом шаблонный код (алгоритма `find_if`) один и тот же для всех типов, которые можно использовать через нотацию вызова функции - круглые скобки. Т.е. как раз то, что предоставляет `operator()`.

В стандартной библиотеке довольно много классов, где реализована перегрузка `operator()`. Например:

- разные распределения случайных величин: `bernoulli_distribution`, `uniform_real_distribution` ...;
- различные унарные и бинарные (арифметические/логические/битовые) операции: `std::logical_not`, `std::bit_and`, `std::less`, `std::minus` ...;
- обёртка над ссылкой `std::reference_wrapper`;
- конечно же, обёртка над функциями `std::function`

и т.п.

Answer (score -1):

На пример, когда делают двумерные массивы склеенные в одномерный, для функторов [вот статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/125995/) и для другого рада облегчения жизни.