# перегрузка операторов c++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Потихоньку разбираюсь с C++. Решил реализовать матрицу используя только "встроенные" возможности C++. Хочу получать значение своей "матрицы" по двум индексам (как-то вот так: `m[i][j]`). Получилось пока только с помощью круглых скобок (`m(i, j)`), но это всё равно не то. Пытаюсь найти доступную информация для понимания - не получается. Поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include "Matrix.h"


Matrix::Matrix() : size(0), data(new int[0]) {}

Matrix::Matrix(unsigned size)
{
    this->size = size;
    this->data = new int[size * size];
    this->init_data();
}

void Matrix::init_data() 
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->size * this->size; i++)
        this->data[i] = rand() % 1000;
}

void Matrix::print_matrix()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < this->size; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << this->data[i * this->size + j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Matrix::insert_zeros()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < this->size; j++)
        {
            if (i > j)
                this->data[i * this->size + j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int& Matrix::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j)
{   
    return this->data[i * this->size + j];
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81432/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8?rq=1 ?

Comment: Пусть первый `[]` (от одного `int`) возвращает указатель на первый элемент соответствующей строки (`int*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас уже все нормально сделано (не считая забытой `const`-перегрузки), нет большого смысла поддерживать другой синтаксис.

Если используете C++23, то можно поменять на `m[i, j]` (просто поменять `operator()` на `operator[]`).

Поддерживать синтаксис `[i][j]` смысла нет. Но если очень хочется, то нужно делать `operator[]` с одним аргументом, и возвращать по значению объект вспомогательного класса, у которого тоже перегружен `[]`. Даже не обязательно городить свой класс, потому что он уже есть в стандартной библиотеке - [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). (Еще можно было бы возвращать просто указатель, но тогда теряем возможность включить проверку границ.)

Получается что-то типа:

```
std::span<int> operator[](std::size_t i)
{   
    return {data + i * size, size};
}

std::span<const int> operator[](std::size_t i) const
{   
    return {data + i * size, size};
}
```

---

Не забываем про правило трех - у вас забыт деструктор, копирующий конструктор и `operator=` и перемещающий конструктор и `operator=`.

Еще, какой бы способ перегрузки `[]` не выбрали, нужно делать две перегрузки: `const` и не-`const`.

Comment: может быть использован  и stdext::checked_array_iterator<PTR>   в качестсве прокси